# Как написать корзину и регистрацию пользователя на PHP в HTML ?

Tags: веб-программирование, php, html

Может вопрос, конечно, и глупый, но сама никак не разберусь :(

В php не разбираюсь, но регистрация и корзина в интернет магазине срочно понадобились... Читала на разных форумах, везде искала - не разобралась :(

Очень поможет пример кода и обьяснения к его работе, и как вставлять в html. Или хотя бы где можно найти подробные инструкции с примерами :(

**Добавлено.**

Вот форма регистрации, как ее дальше использовать не пойму

```
<form id="register_form" name="register_form" method="post" action="">
<table width="508" height="231" border="1" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
<tr>
<td width="251" align="right">Login:</td>
<td width="251" align="center">
<input type="text" name="rlogin" id="rlogin" />
</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Password:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="password" name="rpass" id="rpass" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">Repeat Password:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="password" name="rpass_r" id="rpass_r" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td align="right">E-Mail:</td>
<td align="center"><input type="text" name="email" id="email" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td colspan="2" align="center">
<input type="submit" name="reg_button" id="reg_button" value=" Register " />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Comment: Тут нужно пятистастраничную книжку писать: Основы PHP.

Comment: Скорее не форма, а обработчик данных полученных от формы. 

Answer (score 1):

Мне жаль вас огорчать, но в html, к сожалению, php вставить нельзя. Для этого нужен хостинг с установленным сервером (apache/iis) и, собственно, php.

зы: что это за магазин такой без регистрации и корзины ?

Comment: это зачетная работа, формурегистрации создать могу но что с ней дальше делать не знаю

Comment: ну вот например: http://www.softtime.ru/info/articlephp.php?id_article=34

только я не пойму, если вы не знаете что такое php и как с ним работать - значит вам не обьясняли, а если вам не объясняли почему же вас заставляют делать то, чего вы не знаете ?

Comment: нам дали распечатки, в которых есть маленькие примеры которые показывают как создавать формы (кнопочки) и тому подобное, как их делать разобралась, а что дальше и как сделать саму регистрацию и корзину и как это связать не пойму :(

огромное спасибо за ссылку :)

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно поднять локальный сервер. На нем разместите файл PHP, который будет обрабатывать данные. У вас указанно: `<form id="register_form" name="register_form" method="post" action="">`. В `action=""`: `login.php` В `login.php` пишете:

```
if(isset($_POST[rpass])){
   $password = $_POST[rpass]; //Теперь у вас есть переменная с паролем.
}

if(isset($_POST[rpass_r])){
   $password_r = $_POST[rpass_r]; 
}

if(password != password_r)
  echo "Пароли не совпадают";
```

И т.д. Только учтите, данные из браузера надо проверять на вредоносный код.

Вот пример:

```
function sanitizeString($string){
   $string = strip_tags($string);
   $string = htmlentities($string);
   $string = stripsplashes($string);
   return mysql_real_escape_string($string);
}
```

Использование:

```
...
$password_r = sanitizeString($_POST[rpass_r]);
...
```

Comment: Вы опоздали на четыре года =)

Comment: Ага, только когда написал заметил )

Answer (score -2):

**1)** К примеру, это будет файл `data.php`

```
<form id="register_form" name="register_form" method="post" action="obrabotka.php">
</form>
```

**2)** А это будет в файле `obrabotka.php`

```
<form id="register_form" name="register_form" method="post" action="save.php">
</form>
```

**3)** Ну, а в файле `save.php` - скрипт сохранения данных в базе.

Comment: Это всего лишь форма для заполнения. Далее необходима еще форма обработки и если надо форма сохранения данных в базе. Формы обработки и сохранения лучше сделать на php
Рекомендую сайт denwer.ru для начала.

Comment: Рекомендую для начала попробовать поработать с набором Denwer, чтобы понять что такое Apache-сервер и PHP. сайт denwer.ru

Comment: Спасибо огроное :) а как потом обе формы связать?

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь стало более понятно :)